# Select columns that have a specific type

Tags: postgresql, select, types

I want to get all columns' names that have a specific type, for example I want to print all the columns' names with int type. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [information_schema.columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) for that:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where data_type = 'integer';
```